# Error to install gdalcubes in R on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: r, gis

When i install gdalcubes on ubuntu 20.04 with R, i have this error :

installing to /home/obstetar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-gdalcubes/00new/gdalcubes/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed

- removing ‘/home/obstetar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/gdalcubes’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdalcubes’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp6dZFPa/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Did you get any other messages / errors? Did you install all the system requirements? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalcubes/index.html

Comment: and see https://github.com/appelmar/gdalcubes_R#linux for ubuntu

Comment: Yes i install with recommended on [gdalcubes_R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalcubes/index.html) , but there is a message on problem with qgis-providers !